# mariaDB Incorrect string value

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I'm a newbie. I have stumbled upon this warning (code 1366) when trying to insert a string with an accent like é in my tables.
For instance if I type this in the prompt:

```
create database db character set = "utf8mb4" collate = "utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
use db; 
create table tab(
    string varchar(10) character set "utf8mb4" collate "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" primary key
) character set "utf8mb4" collate "utf8mb4_unicode_ci";

insert into tab value("ö");
```

I get the mentioned warning, and the character is saved as a question mark. (I'm aware that the code looks repetitive, but it's just for the purpose of diagnosing the problem).

I have read a dozen of questions about this warning on stackoverflow in the past hours and have learned that utf8 is not suited and that I should use utf8mb4 instead.
This documentation page [documentation page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/) in the paragraph "Example: Changing the Default Character Set To UTF-8" says to change/add some lines in the my.ini file, and also suggests utf8mb4 (rather than utf8). But despite the changes, the issue is still present.

I'll show that all the possible variables have successfully been set to utf8mb4 (except character_set_system, which is read-only so I assume it's not part of the problem):

```
MariaDB [db]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.021 sec)
```

I'm running the last version of MariaDB, 10.4
Any help is appreciated

**Edit**

@RickJames I'm just launching mysql from the command prompt of Xampp. The hex is 94 actually. It always prints a question mark instead of the desired character. If I type

```
select 'à';
```

the following is returned:

```
+---+
| ? |
+---+
| à  |
+---+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Also, I have just noticed that if I launch mysql from Windows prompt rather than Xampp's shell, I can insert the accented letters and print them correctly, so I may stick to cmd.
Notice the difference in the result when typing the same command as before:

```
+---+
| à |
+---+
| à |
+---+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Still, after successfully adding the value "ö" in my tab from cmd, if I open mysql in Xampp's shell and do a select of the table from there, it prints gibberish (in particular these two characters together: ├Â).

Comment: What client are you using (PHP/Java/etc)?  Did `ö` get inserted?  What is the hex of that character (`SELECT HEX(col) ...`)?  `F6` for latin1 or `C3B6` for utf8mb4?  When you `SELECT the character does it come back `Ã¶` (Mojibake`) or something else?  See "best practices" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: 90% that the symbol is corrupted even before it is stuffed into the connection or after it is pulled out. MySQL/MariaDB have no problems with such symbols itself. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnDzX.png